# Raw_input, multithreading, and timeout in raspberry pi

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, raw-input

I've been looking around it seems to be a real headache so I had to be clear that I'm using Raspberry Pi. I'm totally new to Python and Linux.

My application requires multiple inputs and processing and what I've come up with is a program running multiple threads.

One of my pieces of hardware is a keyboard emulator so I have to use raw_input (or is there an alternative?).

The problem is all threads seem to pause when raw_input executes and finishes. Right now, I'm looking into using raw_input with timeout. I tried using the `select` method but I've been getting:

```
rlist, _, _ = select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno()
```

Do you have any suggestion on what to do here? Thank you!

Comment: `The problem is all threads seem to pause when raw_input executes and finishes.` This should not happen.

Comment: @Faust Probably it's with the raspberry pi? I'm sure of this because I even tried a program where a thread would simply print "." forever then prompt the user with `raw input` after a second. This would cause the printing of dots to cease and continue only after enter is pressed.

Comment: This thread points the blame at the Raspberry pi: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/raspberry-pi-arduino-other-sbcs/99251-kill-process-es-running-script-linux.html